# Is there a good role based workflow engine in PHP?

Tags: php, workflow

I am looking for role based access and work flow engine that allows for simple configuration.

Answer (score 3):

i use the Zend Framework, so i guess to create auth/roles/resources/acl, i will use the respective classes

- [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html)
- [Zend_Acl_Role](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html#zend.acl.introduction.roles)
- [Zend_Acl_Resource](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html#zend.acl.introduction.resources)
- [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html)

to determine if a user (role) is allowed access to a resource, do something like

```
// setup variables
$acl = new Zend_Acl();
$adminRole = new Zend_Acl_Role("admin");
$adminResource = new Zend_Acl_Resource("adminResource");

// add roles, resources to acl
$acl->addRole($adminRole);
$acl->addResource($adminResource);

// add rules
$acl->allow($adminRole, $adminResource);

// query acl
echo $acl->isAllowed($adminRole, $adminResource) ? "allowed" : "denied"; // allowed
```

something like above

Comment: This deals with auth and roles, what about enforcing a workflow?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [ezComponents workflow](http://www.ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/Workflow). We built an intranet application using it and it was quite easy to use. The documentation is awesome and it has very active community.

Update: ezComponents now lives on as [Zeta Components](https://github.com/zetacomponents)

Comment: Sad, but it looks that ezComponents project is abandoned for last 4 years :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a php framework that'll make roles easy ? I'd suggest Symfony. A sample security.yml file looks like

```
all:
  is_secure:  on
  credentials: Admin
```

The security files  also cascade, so you can put this on the highest level (App level) and override it on a module or page level.

Or am I totally off ?

Comment: I am looking for something that can be used across the application as a way to allow or deny access to a set of functions on the PHP pages.

Comment: You want to do this on a per function level instead of a per php-script/page level ?

Comment: I'd say you've some design flaw when you want to do this on function level. I mean, the user can't choose which functions your script is gonna call. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[PHP acl](http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/) worked really well for me. several open source projects are using it like joomla, in the other hand cakephp take the code model to make it own acl system

Answer (score 0):

Tony Marston has one, maybe you could contact him:
http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/workflow.html